# Plotting array values with matplotlib, only first half is shown

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a numpy array of some 120K elements, most of them are 0s, but there are some groups of 1s.
[This](https://filedropper.com/d/s/AvvVodbSnr3F2tqXQFyeWMWmHr8Hpn) is a link to the csv file containing the data.

I'm plotting this array, and everything seems pretty straightforward:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

input_data = pd.read_csv('input.csv').to_numpy()[0]
# input.shape -> (126946,)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(600, 50), nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=40)
ax1.plot(range(len(input_data)), input_data, color='green', label='input', linewidth=1)
fig.savefig(f'file_name.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The image is produced and saved, but only about the first half of the intervals is actually shown:

[image: produced image]

I'm sure there are other intervals of non zero elements in the array, I printed the last non-zero values, and they are well past the point where the plot stops.

EDIT:
Increasing the line width didn't change anything, but decreasing the overall figure width:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(400, 50), nrows=1, ncols=1)
```

produced the expected result:

[image: complete plot]

Comment: please provide the shape of your input or mock it with numpy

Comment: Second half of your array could consist of NaNs, as the line is invisible.

Comment: Also, what does the plot look like with a smaller figure width? With 600 inches, and 100 dpi, the line might also be too thin too visualize (although I can't explain why you would see the first half of the data).